# Prove that $\oint_{\partial S} \psi \; d\ell = \iint_S (\hat{\mathbf{n}} \times \nabla \psi) \; dS$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

In the Wikipedia article on [vector calculus identities](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Vector_calculus_identities#Curve.E2.80.93surface_integrals),
we have the following

$$\oint_{\partial S} \psi \; d\ell = \iint_S (\hat{\mathbf{n}} \times \nabla \psi) \; dS$$

How do I prove this? I tried Stokes' theorem, to no avail.
Perhaps there are some identities for exterior derivatives that I'm not aware of
which may be useful.

Comment: Err...  That is the (Kelvin-)Stokes theorem...  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes%27_theorem#Kelvin.E2.80.93Stokes_theorem

Comment: Kelvin-Stokes states that the surface integral of the curl is equal to the line integral on the boundary. I don't see why this reduces to that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Pick an arbitrary constant vector $e$, and take the inner product with it on both sides. Then use Stokes theorem to prove that
$$ \int_{\partial S}\psi\,(e,dl) = \int_S(e,dS\times \nabla \psi). $$

Comment: Question: what does the volume form $dS$ mean here? It's certainly not the flux integral of $n \times \nabla \psi$. Where can I find a good reference for this? (I haven't seen this notation anywhere else)

Comment: @user908123 $dS$ is a vector pointing in the direction of the normal to surface, with its length equal to the area of the infinitesimal surface element. This is the same as $\mathbf{n}\,dS$ in another notation.